# substitute array values for mysql insert statement

Tags: python, mysql, linux

I am trying to execute an insert statement for MySQL with the list of array values..but it didn't work..

My "array" list has all the required values

```
insert_statement = "insert into db (Hostname,Serial_Number,cpu,memory,Eth0_IP,Eth1_IP,hardware_type,datacenter,Operating_System) values ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s') % (array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3], array[4], array[5], array[6], array[7], array[8])"

cur.execute(insert_statement)
```

I also tried

```
insert_statement = "insert into db (Hostname,Serial_Number,cpu,memory,Eth0_IP,Eth1_IP,hardware_type,datacenter,Operating_System) values ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s') , array"

cur.executemany(insert_statement)
```

both are erroring out with "sql statement errors".

Comment: Can you post what `insert_statement` looks like after the variable values are inserted and before it's executed?

Comment: Which MySQL module do you use? _mysql?

Comment: You are doing percent interpolation which is no no, and you're using it within the query. Please do the query in `insert_statement` without any `%` and then do `cur.execute(insert_statement, array)`

Answer (score 1):

With MySQLdb this should work (if your array consists of 9 elements):

```
insert_statement = "insert into db (Hostname,Serial_Number,cpu,memory,Eth0_IP,Eth1_IP,hardware_type,datacenter,Operating_System) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"

cur.execute(insert_statement, array)
```